# Functional Programming: Calling a Curried Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, currying

I'm implementing the game *Tic Tac Toe*/*Naughts and Crosses* in a functional programming style and have stumbled across a hurdle with curried functions.

I have a reoccurring pattern of functions in the form `func(width, height, index)` which I then wish to curry, binding `width` and `height` and leaving `curriedFunc(index)`.

However the problem arises when I have functions that expect one of these curried functions to be defined at compile-time.

They cannot be defined at compile time, because they need input from the user to then bind the values to the function.

Below is some example code of the pattern I've encountered.

```
// Board indexes:
//  0 | 1 | 2
// ---+---+---
//  3 | 4 | 5
// ---+---+---
//  6 | 7 | 8

const getRowNumGivenWidth = w => i => Math.floor(i/w);

// I want to be able to declare nextIndexInRowGivenWidth() here, outside of main()
// but getRowNum() needs to be defined beforehand


const main = () => {

  // User input:
  const width = 3;

  // ...


  const getRowNum = getRowNumGivenWidth(width);

  const nextIndexInRowGivenWidth = width => currentIndex => {
    const rowNum = getRowNum(currentIndex);
    const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (getRowNum(nextIndex) != rowNum)
      result = nextIndex - width;
    else
      result = nextIndex;

    return result;
  };


  const nextIndexInRow = nextIndexInRowGivenWidth(width);

  const board = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  board.map(x => console.log(x, " -> ", nextIndexInRow(x)));

  // ...

}

main();
```

The only way I can think of solving this is to pass the curried function as an argument (to `nextIndexInRowGivenWidth()` in this example).

However I don't think this is ideal as if a function requires a few similarly curried functions at run-time, it quickly becomes unwieldy to define and curry said function.

The ideal solution would be if I could somehow make the binding of the values dynamic, suppose I could put the declaration `getRowNum = getRowNumGivenWidth(width);` before `main()`. This way I could call something like `getRowNum(someInt)` to initialise `getRowNum()` which I could then use in other functions that are already expecting it to be defined.

As this is a reoccurring pattern in my code, I was wondering if there is a design pattern to achieve this.

Comment: There is no compile time. Nor is it at all clear why you're wrapping your code in a 'main' function. You can also create functions *anytime* and you can always use `.bind` to partially apply parameters. It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly used "compile-time" to refer to "before program execution". The `main()` was just to indicate the entry point of the code and how the functions would be called. It does seem like `.bind` can achieve what I'm trying to do, but is it a functional construct?

Comment: "Is it a functional construct" isn't that putting the cart before the horse? Does it lead to easier code reuse? Easy to maintain? Read? Although `.bind` is frequently used OO-style to manually set the `this` pointer, it can also be used in FP to partially apply: `const add = (x, y) => x + y; const add3 = add.bind(null, 3); const five = add3(2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
const getRowNumGivenWidth = w => i => Math.floor(i/w);

const nextIndexInRowGivenWidth = width => {
  const getRowNum = getRowNumGivenWidth(width);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return currentIndex => {
    const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (getRowNum(nextIndex) != getRowNum(currentIndex))
      return nextIndex - width;
    else
      return nextIndex;
  };
};

const main = () => {
  // User input:
  const width = 3;
  const nextIndexInRow = nextIndexInRowGivenWidth(width);

  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could define that `nextIndexInRowGiven…` function not with the `width` as the first curried parameter, but with `getRowNum` itself as the parameter:

```
const getRowNumGivenWidth = w => i => Math.floor(i/w);

const nextIndexInRowGivenRowNumGetter = getRowNum => currentIndex => {
  const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

  if (getRowNum(nextIndex) != getRowNum(currentIndex))
    return nextIndex - width;
  else
    return nextIndex;
};

const main = () => {
  // User input:
  const width = 3;
  const nextIndexInRow = nextIndexInRowGivenRowNumGetter(getRowNumGivenWidth(width));

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like both ideas. I think the first will be more beneficial in this situation because it's more likely that many of the smaller functions will be bound to `width` and `height` specifically.

In the second method, it becomes unruly if many functions are required to be passed in, which may be a possibility as the code grows.

Using the first method you could have a function `f(w, h, i)` and then bind all the smaller functions inside as they all rely on `w` and `h`.